# Multicolor and Multicolumn/row table

Tags: tables

I haven't started on this because I have no idea where to begin. Is it possible to make a table like this in LaTeX? I haven't started the tex document yet.

[image]

Comment: Your table is very complex.

Comment: Yea it is :( gah!

Comment: The problem is that there are many times to create a table. It is very irrealistic that somebody help you.